# Type mismatch error due to leading apostrophe in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have encountered error of

> Type Mismatch

at the line of

```
stSubject = (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AD").Value) + " " + 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AE").Value) + " " + 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AF").Value) + " " + 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AG").Value) + " " + 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AH").Value) + " " + 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AI").Value)
```

My worksheet format looks like below:
[image]

Please ignore the mismatch of column name as the code I provided above. For cell at column P and U, thee must be an apostrophe added in the beginning of the cell, so that I could send the lotus notes email using my macro. Do avoid the trouble that I need to add an apostrophe for every cell, I need to either get Excel ignore the apostrophe character or add the character automatically, so I'm curious which method do you guys prefer? And how do I solve that?

Comment: Can you post sample value for each of the columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel automatically ignores the apostrophe, so that is actually not the problem.

Try using `&` instead of `+`. The `+` only works as concatenate if all the input values are strings. If there is a number (or date) among them, VBA tries to add them mathematically, and you get a Type mismatch error.

```
stSubject = (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AD").Value) & " " & 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AE").Value) & " " & 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AF").Value) & " " & 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AG").Value) & " " & 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AH").Value) & " " & 
            (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AI").Value)
```

Comment: Thank you this of of great help.

Comment: Hi I have currently encountered a problem with & concatenation. Now datetime column shows value such as 42150.91666666 instead of proper format like 5/26/2015 10:00:00 PM, do you have any clue how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, use the `format()` function. Use this for a **proper** format: `format(42150.91666666,"yyyy-mm-dd")` :) For the random-ordered American format, use it like this: `format(42150.91666666,"m/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM")`. Concatenate this with the rest of your data.